# Ubuntu 20.04 nvidia driver reset

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to `Ubuntu 20.04` and I found out the `Additional Driver` can install required Nvidia driver preferred by the OS.
Although, it works fine after installing but after every month (roughly) somehow the driver gets reset or something causing weird graphics rendering issue and sluggish behavior of the desktop.
This thing could be resolved by switching to other driver (which is aparently not recommended by `Additional Driver` for my `QuadroK4200`) and re-switching to the recommended driver and followed by a reboot.
This is a very annoying issue I never had to face with any other Linux OS.
I'd highly appreciate if you please suggest anything to resolve this.
Thanks.

Comment: What driver version are you installing?  Sometimes the one that states recommended many not be the best one for the card.  Looking at NVIDIA's site, the 470 driver is good for it.  https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/184163/en-us

Comment: I did install 470 as it was recommended. Kept auto update off to keep the system stable. This is very odd.